# How can I remove text that has been added into a paragraph with +=

Tags: javascript

I messed up my first time asking this. But how can I remove text added to an element via +=. My javascript currectly looks like this:

```
printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed){
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
        i++;
        if (i > message.length){
        clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }, speed);
}
function clear(destination){
document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML=""
}
```

and my html:

```
<p id="storyStarter" onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;storyStarter&quot;).innerHTML=&quot;&quot;; printLetterByLetter(&quot;storyStarter&quot;,&quot; It all begins here&quot;,50)">Click To begin Story</p>
<a onclick="clear(&quot;storyStarter&quot;)">Clear Text</a>
```

it prints to the page but clicking on the remover doesn't remove the text.

Comment: have you tried writing out to the console what's being passed into the clear function to check it's what you expected?

Comment: Why do you complicating the input of the function?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the name `clear` is already used for something in the browser, probably the [document.clear method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear).

If you use a different name for the function, it works fine:

```js
function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed){
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
        i++;
        if (i > message.length){
        clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }, speed);
}

function empty(destination){
  document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML=""
}
```

```html
<p id="storyStarter" onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;storyStarter&quot;).innerHTML=&quot;&quot;; printLetterByLetter(&quot;storyStarter&quot;,&quot; It all begins here&quot;,50)">Click To begin Story</p>
<a onclick="empty(&quot;storyStarter&quot;)">Clear Text</a>
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function name which is called on  click, like..

```
<a onclick="clearText(&quot;storyStarter&quot;)">Clear Text</a>

function clearText(destination){
   document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML=""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with function name `clear`. I think it is a reserved word. Just change the name and it will work.

**HTML**

```
<p id="storyStarter" onclick="document.getElementById('storyStarter').innerHTML='';printLetterByLetter('storyStarter','It all begins here',50)">Click To begin Story</p>
```

Clear Text

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed){
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
    i++;
    if (i > message.length){
    clearInterval(interval)
    }
 }, speed);
}
function clearing(destination){
    document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML=""
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/7vh5g7kv/)